# Selecting files in Nautilus 3.26.2

Tags: linux, gnome, file-management, nautilus

Since 3.26 I cannot drag-select files in Nautilus in folders. The rectangle just does not appear. Currently I can select only successive filen in rows.

However, drag-selection works on desktop.
How do I return normal selection? Is it a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting Gnome 3 settings with `dconf reset -f /` solved the problem. It should have been a bug, not a feature.

**Update:** it turned out that I had enabled this kind of experimental selection in the settings of Nautilus.

Comment: might be worth rounding off your answers with some references and what this command actually does

Comment: Fck.  Stupid me just following this "fix" at face value.  It reset my desktop and got rid of all my customizations.  And it didn't fix the nautilus issue.